# query execution duration is different for same queries in mysql even if cache is set to off

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I got different execution duration for the same queries even if the query cache is set to OFF.

DATABASE that i'm using is MYSQL and Db Engine is InnoDB.

Anyone please tell why this nondisciplinary duration happens for the same queries?.

Comment: There are many things that might affect this. Did the DB change? Rows added/deleted/changed?
Furthermore it could be that the host computer is doing other things at one point and doesn't give enough CPU time to the MYSQL process.

Comment: DB changed but both DB are same except Name.